# what is this return line indicates from java AES encryption method?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

This is a block of code from AES encrytion method:

```
 public  String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
        try {
            setKey(myKey);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In this code what exactly are we returning to the encrypt method? What does this line here indicate?

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, encryption is almost always a `byte[]`-to-`byte[]` thing. So if you want *either* the input or the output (or both) to be readable `String` values, then you'll need to do some transformation on the way in and/or on the way out. In this case we do a transformation both ways:

1. `strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")` takes the input `String` `strToEncrypt` and converts it into a `byte[]` using the UTF-8 encoding (a good choice, because it can represent all of Unicode, is universally known/compatible and reasonably compact).
2. Then `cipher.doFinal(...)` is the call that executes the actual encryption. Taking the input from #1 and returning a `byte[]` with the cypher text ("text" is misleading, because that `byte[]` does **not** represent readable text, it'll effectively look like binary random noise).
3. `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(...)` then receives the `byte[]` returned by `doFinal` and will encode it using `Base64` to get a readable text that represents that binary data.

So in short: encrypts some `String` and returns the result in a format that *could* be read by humans, but will almost certainly only be meaningful to a computer.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed information. I am trying to learn about encryption techniques, still unfamiliar with some terms. This is helpful.